# NSPredicate confusion with Nested Arrays of custom objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have a custom object, which is in the format:

```
@interface GroupModel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *groupId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *children;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *instruments;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;

@end
```

The instruments array is an array of custom models in the form of:

```
@interface InstrumentModel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *instrumentId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;

@end
```

And the children array in the GroupModel, is an array of GroupModel objects.
The reason behind this is to create a tree-like structure, so a root group can have multiple child groups, each of them can contain instruments and/or child groups.

Kinda like a folder/file format

Now what I'm trying is to search for a given instrument Id in a given GroupModel.
The instrumentId might be in the given model in the instruments array, or it might be in any children group models instruments array.

What kind of predicate would I need to be using, as I'm confused.
Would this require a subquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This has worked for me:

```
            //Create an array to add all InstrumentGroup Objects
            NSMutableArray * allChildren = [NSMutableArray new];

            //add the root group instruments
            [allChildren addObjectsFromArray:rootGroup.instruments];
            //now add the children's of children Instruments using the unionOfArrays Collection operator
            [allChildren addObjectsFromArray:[rootGroup.children valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.instruments"]];
            //add the children's children instruments
            [allChildren addObjectsFromArray:[rootGroup.children valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.children.@unionOfArrays.instruments"]];

            //filter the Instrument objects
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY instruments.instrumentId == %@",selectedInstrumentId];
            filtered = [allChildren filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

            if (filtered.count>0) {
                //found the instrument!
                InstrumentModel *instrument = filtered.firstObject;
            }
```